# How not to expose duplicated (normalize?) nodes via GraphQL?

Tags: optimization, graphql, normalization

Given "user has many links" (what means a link was created by a user) DB entities relations, I want to develop API to fetch links along with users so that the returned data does not contain duplicated users.

In other words, instead of this request:

```
query {
  links {
    id
    user {
      id email
    }
  }
}
```

that returns the following data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "links": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "user": {
          "id": 2,
          "email": "user2@example.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "user": {
          "id": 2,
          "email": "user2@example.com"
        }
      }
  ]
  }
}
```

I want to make a request like this (note the "references" column):

```
query {
  links {
    id
    userId
  }
  references {
    users {
      id
      email
    }
  }
}
```

that returns associated users without duplicates:

```
{
  "data": {
    "links": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "userId": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "userId": 2
      },
    ],
    "references": {
      "users": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "email": "user2@example.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That should reduce amount of data transferred between client and server that adds a bit of speed boost.

Is there ready common implementation on any language of that idea? (Ideally, seeking for Ruby)

Answer (score 0):

### It's not a query or server role to normalize data.

- there are no such possibilities in GraphQL specs;
- server must return all asked fields within queried [response] structure;

... but you can implement some:

- standarized (commonly used) pagination (relay style `edges`/`nodes`, `nodes` only or better both);
- query [complexity] weights to promote this optimized querying style - **separate problem**;
- reference dictionary field within queried type;

```
      links {
        egdes {
          node {
            id
            title
            url
            authorId
    #  possible but limited usage with heavy weights
    #       author {
    #         id
    #         email
    #       }
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPages
        }
        referencedUsers {
          id
          email
        }
      }
```

where:

- `User` has `id` and `email` props;
- `referencedUsers` is `[User!]` type;
- `node.author` is `User` type;

Normalizing Graphql client, like `Apollo`, can easily access cached user fields without making separate requests.

You can render (react?) some `<User/>` component (within `<Link />` component) passing `node.authorId` as an argument like `<User id={authorId} />`. User component can `useQuery` hook with `cache-only` policy to read user props/fields.

See Apollo docs for details. You should implement this for yourself and document this to help/guide API users.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'm aware that Apollo has a cache system that won't query data from back-end if it's already fetched by a key `Type#id`. That, of course, is nice. But the question relates more to reduce traffic data between server and client.

Comment: And how to implement this tricky resolver that would allow to select referenced entities in a separate structure.

Comment: [probably] you won't reduce traffic without weighted queries ... IDK ruby ... in general [graphql resolving flow] it can be like ... `links` resolver reads records from one DB table, simply collect user ids into some array (save in `links` result object beside edges/nodes and pagination info), use it in `referencedUsers` resolver (by `parent`, the 1st arg) to fetch users from 2nd DB table